# Can an app create a "virtual" HMAccesory?

Tags: ios, tvos, homekit

Apple offers a **HomeKit Accessory Simulator** -- a software tool that simulates a hardware device.

Is there a way to have an iOS (or tvOS) app do something similar? That is, can an iOS or tvOS app create a purely software-based HMAccessory?